# Is there a smooth rationally connected, proper variety $M$ over $\mathbb{C}$ such that c_1(L)([A]) = 1 which is not projective space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, examples

Is there a smooth, rationally connected, projective variety $M$, which is not a projective space and is equipped with an ample line bundle $L$, such that the homology class of the curves $[A]$ which connect any two points satisfies $c_1(L)([A])=1$?

This is closely related (but not equivalent) to my other question

[G.W. invariants $<[pt],[pt]>_{0,[A]} \neq 0$ such that there exists ample L with $c_1(L)([A])=1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178168/g-w-invariants-pt-pt-0-a-neq-0-such-that-there-exists-ample-l-with)

but phrased in a classical way.